# What is the probability that he or she spent at least 1000 dollars?

Tags: probability

In a shop,20% of the customers spend at least 1000 dollars.Among those spending at least 1000 dollars, 30% pay by credit card,while among those spending less that 1000 dollars, only 10% pay by credit card. Suppose a randomly chosen customer is found to have paid by credit card. What is the probability that he or she spent  at least 1000 dollars?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Let $A$ be the event that a customer spends at least $\$1000$, and $B$ the event that a customer pays by credit card. You are given the values of $P(A)$, $P(B\mid A)$ and $P\left(B\mid A^c\right)$ and are asked to find $P(A\mid B)$. Do you know how to do this? (Do you know Bayes' Rule and the Law of Total Probability?)

Comment: I don't really know bayes rule but now I know how to do it thanks  (I really shouldnt have skipped those lessons :( )